# SURD/Differential Question - Did they rationalise the fraction?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am doing this question but don't understand this solution. Did they rationalise the SURD on this step?
[image]

If you would like context in terms of the whole question here it is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$ \frac{dh}{dt}= -k\sqrt h= -k'\frac{\sqrt{Ah}}{A} $$
so 
$$ k=k' \frac{\sqrt{Ah}}{A\sqrt h}=k' \sqrt\frac{Ah}{A^2h} =\frac{k'}{\sqrt A}$$

Comment: Hi, I am a bit confused as to what you have done on the second line. Why have you multiplied the denominator by root H?

Comment: I have divided both sides of $-k\sqrt h= -k'\frac{\sqrt{Ah}}{A}$ by $-\sqrt h$